# Django aggregation: average occurrences over unique field

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.8

I'm breaking my head over the following aggregation. I want to get amount of different pages the average device checks between date x and y.

Pseudocode for model:

```
class Statistic:
    device_id = int
    date = date
    page_id = int
```

Anyone know how to complete this:

```
Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x,date__lte=y).???
```

---

UPDATE: in case the question is not clear, here is an example:

- Get all the unique device_id values that occur in the table.
- For each of those unique device_id values, count the amount of unique page_id values that occur in the table. Add those values to a list.
- Calculate the average of that list.

But that involves a query in a loop, a new query for each device_id, which is obviously not very efficient. I'm looking for a way to do that in 1-2 queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "checks", is there relation with another model `Device` or something?

If I get it, you want to get all Statistic between `x` and `y` dates, and aggregate to know which device checked it in order to summarize and get an average?

Comment: The dates are of less importance here. These are iOS/Android stats and device_id refers to the device uuid, but it could be seen as user_id. I want to know how many pages (= distinct page_id's) the average user visits.

Comment: So, you want to get each Statistic for a given device_id, and as I understand you want to know for each UNIQUE page visited (once), how many pages has been visited by device. Iterate for all devices and get the average of unique visited pages?

Comment: No, the device_id is not given. I think something like this: for each unique device_id, see how many unique page_id's it has. Then take the average of that list. But like that there would be a query for each and every device_id. I'm looking for a way to do this in 1 or 2 queries.

Comment: Ok, so the device_id and page_id in Statistic is related to a page visit right?

Comment: Yes you could see it that way. I have improved the explanation in the UPDATE part of the original post.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Would be good if you're on PostgreSQL since it can handle specific DISTINCT queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm thinkin clear, this should do it:

```
Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x,date__lte=y).values('device_id').annotate(count=Count('device_id')).aggregate(avg=Avg('count'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x, date__lte=y).distinct('device_id', 'page_id').values('device_id', 'page_id')`

Will give you the Queryset showing pages visited once by device, distinctly (in a unique way) and only retrieving the data you want.

Then you can use Python to compute this :

```
data = Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x, date__lte=y).distinct('device_id', 'page_id').values('device_id', 'page_id')
devices_set = set([d['device_id'] for d in data])
grouped = dict([(d, []) for d in devices_set])
for d in data:
    for g in grouped:
        if d['device_id'] == g:
            grouped[g].append(d['page_id'])
```

You then have all unique `page_id` visited by `deviced_id` in a Python dict, you can do whatever you want with.

Since the model you gave doesn't seems to be related to other model, I don't know if we can optimize the Queryset better to do it database side, tough this will work.

Comment: Hey Maxime, thanks for your help. The problem with this is that it will kill memory, as the statistics lines could be many many. That's why I preferred to do it on the database side.

Comment: Then you'll have to make some other tables (models) to join on these. Eg. making device_id a ForeignKey (and page_id aswell?)

Comment: Well or simply a raw SQL with a nested query. In raw SQL I have no problem expressing this.

Comment: So why not using RawSQL then?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get average number of pages each device checks between x and y dates,

For that you need to find number of unique devices which you can do like this:

```
devices= Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x,date__lte=y).values('device_id').distinct().count()
```

Now find the number of objects within this range:

```
pages = Statistic.objects.filter(date__gte=x,date__lte=y).count()    
avg_pages_per_device = pages/devices
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, then this proposed solution is not correct.